# Remove an element while iterating a list

Tags: java, collections, foreach, iterator

I am trying to remove an element from a list using `Iterator`, but I am getting the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Code:

```
for (Iterator<Punk> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Punk p = iterator.next();

    if (some condition ) {
        iterator.remove();
    }

    index += 1;
}
```

I am just using `iterator.next()` once in the loop everytime so that it will move to the next element. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add whole stacktrace?

Comment: Not sure what `index` is for, but it doesn't seem relevant to this question.

Comment: You define iter, then don't use it?  Where did iterator come from?

Comment: In for loop you declare your iterator variable as `iter` but removing from `iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `iterator` but you iterate this list using `iter`. Make sure your variable names are correct.

```
for (Iterator<Punk> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Punk p = iter.next();

    if (some condition ) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: and this can be further reduced with `list.removeIf(p -> some condition);`

Comment: I prefer the `while` loop approach to this. Putting an `Iterator` in a `for` looks... clunky.

Comment: @Aominè tahnks for the suggestion. But we are using java 7 :)

Comment: @Bucket thanks. i have created another iterator and using that. Sorry for wasting time here. i wonder somtimes how these silly mistakes takes so much time :/

Comment: Most of the problems posted here are "silly mistakes" in hindsight. Sometimes it's just not apparent when you're fatigued from staring at your code for hours on end. As long as we arrive at a solution, time isn't wasted.